# Sending message to JMS (Weblogic)

Tags: queue, jms, weblogic, message-queue, weblogic12c

When I run the following code it seems that the message was sent to the queue but I can not see anythyng on the queue. There is no error, exception durig executing my code.

I use Weblogic server.

**This is my code:**

```
private InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
    env.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    return new InitialContext(env);
}

public ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory(InitialContext context) throws NamingException {
    return (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(ConnectionParameter.JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI);
}

public void send() throws NamingException, JMSException {
    InitialContext context = getInitialContext();
    Destination destination = (Destination) context.lookup("jms/dpdr/mhcinterface/arnoldQueue");

    try (Connection connection = getConnectionFactory(context).createConnection();){
        Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer sender = session.createProducer(destination);
        Message message = session.createTextMessage("work order complete!");
        sender.send(message);
        session.commit();
        session.close();
    }
    context.close();

    System.out.println("-- end --");
}
```

Any idea what is wrong here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to call connection.start() before sending your message. You can do it like below:

```
MessageProducer sender = session.createProducer(destination);
connection.start();
Message message = session.createTextMessage("work order complete!");
```